# How is Hausdorff property of $X$ used in the theorem regarding completeness of $C(X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand a proof of the following theorem (from *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory* by Douglas):

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> Where is the Hausdorff property used in the proof?

Comment: You don't need Hausdorffness. Let $\sim$ be the smallest equivalence relation on $X$ such that $\sim$ is a closed subset of $X \times X$; then every continuous map $X \to \mathbb{R}$ will factor through the quotient map $X \to X / {\sim}$. But $X / {\sim}$ is compact Hausdorff as soon as $X$ is compact, and this argument shows that $C (X) \cong C (X / {\sim})$.

Comment: @ZhenLin True. But it's much simpler to just note that Hausdorff is simply not used at any point in the proof.

Comment: where did you found this proof ?

Comment: @Surb ??? It's exactly the standard argument - you can find it anywhere the result is proved.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Indeed. But this observation lets us make the same conclusion without inspecting the proof.

Comment: I was asking, because may be in the proof they use a result that they proved only on Hausdorff space that would explain why the precise that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @ZhenLin True. Also works for readers who are somehow unable to inspect the proof...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that Hausdorff *is* used; the result is true for compact $K$. They state the result for compact Hausdorff $K$ just because  nobody cares about $C(K)$ for non-Hausdorff compact $K$.

Comment: Of course it is used.

Comment: @Surb Where? You say in your answer that it is used to show that a neighborhood of $x_0$ is not just $\{x_0\}$. _That_ fact is not used in the proof.

Comment: How would you justify that there is an $x\in U\backslash \{x_0\}$ such that $|f_N(x_0)-f_N(x)|<3\varepsilon$ (7th line of the proof).

Comment: You don't need to. You just want to prove it for any $x \in U$.

Comment: @Surb Why would you imagine that fact is needed? You're familiar with how the empty set works, right? A statement "for every $x\in E\dots$ does not imply or require that $E$ be nonempty.

Comment: @Surb You might also note, come to think of it, that it's not even _true_ that Hausdorff implies that a neighborhood of $x_0$ cannot be $\{x_0\}$.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was important. Then sorry for the disturbing :-)

Comment: @Surb I'm about to make an unimportant edit to my post, just so that whoever downvoted it is not stumped by the "cannot change vote until post is edited" rule...

Comment: By the way, I'm the downvoter, and I'm sorry for that. I thought you were wrong. So if you edit again, I will erase my downvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the Hausdorff property is used.

In fact, as far as I can tell, even the compactness is only needed for the suprema to exist.

So in fact, if you allow a metric to be $\infty$ at some pairs, the same proof shows that $C(X)$ is a complete metric space for *any* topological space $X$.

Even if you insist that metrics should never assume $\infty$, it still shows that $C_b(X)$ (the space of *bounded* continuous functions) is always a complete metric space (in this case, you need to notice that an uniform limit of bounded functions is bounded, but that is trivial).